# React router 1.0.0-beta3 just doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, react-router

Am I doing something wrong? this.props.children doesn't get rendered when i go to this URL http://localhost:7000/#/about

--// file name: main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';
import { history } from 'react-router/lib/BrowserHistory';

import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper.react";
import ThumbnailContainer from './components/ThumbnailContainer.react';

React.render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={Wrapper}>
        <Route path="/about" components={ThumbnailContainer}>
        </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body);
```

--//file name:Wrapper.react.js

```
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return(
            {
               className : "p-wrapper p-blue-theme"
            }
        );
    },
    render: function () {
        return(
          <div className={this.state.className} >
              {this.props.children}
          </div>
        );
    }
});

exports['default'] = Wrapper;
module.exports = exports['default'];
```

--// file name:ThumbnailContainer.react.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ThumbnailContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="p-thumbnail-container">
            <a className="p-thumbnail" href="#">
                    <div className="p-thumbnail-img-container"> 
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" className="p-thumbnail-img" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="p-thumbnail-caption">
                        <h3 className="p-title">Thumbnail Title</h3>
                        <h4 className="p-sub-title">Thumbnail Sub Title</h4>
                        <p className="p-description">Thumbnail Description Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ThumbnailContainer;
```

Comment: Does it work if you go to the URL without the hash?

Answer (score 1):

Change components={ThumbnailContainer} to **component**={ThumbnailContainer}.

Comment: I changed it, it still doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '/' from '/about'.  The route is nested so I believe that the leading '/' after the '/' default route is redundant.  Let us know if that works.